# How to point to references with superscripts

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a research paper and try to put my sources on the last page.

I would like to this in such a manner, that when I point to a source in a sentence, if it is for example the third source I use, that there is a ^3 at the end of the sentence.

At the reference page, at the third source, I want to have ^3: reference name.... etc.

Can anybody tell me how to code this?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you don't want to use the default `\cite{}` for `thebibliography` environment? See here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of BibTeX and the simultaneous creation of a bibliography (usually, but not necessarily, located toward the end of a document) and callouts to the bibliographic entries via `\cite` commands? Assuming you want to `\cite` bibliographic entries using a superscript citation style (instead of either an author-year style or a plain-numeric style), you could load the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) citation management package with the `super` option.

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `cite` with the `super` and `biblabel` options does nearly everything you request:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super,biblabel]{cite}

\begin{document}

My document with a citation\cite{art1} and another
citation\cite{book1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{art1} `An article', A.N.~Author, Jour. \textbf{3}(4), 2001,
  21--65.
\bibitem{book1} ``A interesting book'', K.~Text, Pub. Publishing,
  2006.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

What is missing is the colon after the label in the bibliography.  To obtain this one can mimic the command run by the `biblabel` option as follows:

[image: Sample with colon]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super]{cite}
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{\@citess{#1}:}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

My document with a citation\cite{art1} and another
citation\cite{book1}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{art1} `An article', A.N.~Author, Jour. \textbf{3}(4), 2001,
  21--65.
\bibitem{book1} ``A interesting book'', K.~Text, Pub. Publishing,
  2006.
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

All the above is for handwritten bibliogrpahies.  In the long run, a better approach is to use `natbib` with `bibtex`, or `biblatex` with `biber`, together with an external database of entries.